# Beginner Help: What is wrong with this method?

Tags: java

I'm creating a Tic Tac Toe game and this is the way I am checking for the win.  I get this list of errors in this section of code:

> /tmp/java_hoEysf/TicTacToe.java:195: error: not a statement       Public
>   void Checkforwin();       ^ /tmp/java_hoEysf/TicTacToe.java:195: error:
>   ';' expected      Public void Checkforwin();
>               ^ /tmp/java_hoEysf/TicTacToe.java:195: error: illegal start of expression         Public void Checkforwin();

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (The code is not complete and I'm just wondering why the method won't work.)

Code:

```
public void checkForWin() {     
    if (board [0][0] + board[0][1] + board[0][2] == 15) {
        btnA3.setText("Ax");
        win = 1;
    }

    if (board [0][0] + board[0][1] + board[0][2] == 30) {
        btnA3.setText("Ao");
        win = 2;
    }

    if (board[1][0] + board[1][1] + board[1][2] == 15) {
        btnA3.setText("Ax");
        win = 1;
    }

    if (board[1][0] + board[1][1] + board[1][2] == 30) {
        btnA3.setText("Ao");
        win = 2;
    }

    if (board[2][0] + board[2][1] + board[2][2] == 15) {
        btnA3.setText("Ax");
        win = 1;
    }

    if (board[2][0] + board[2][1] + board[2][2] == 30) {
        btnA3.setText("Ao");
        win = 2;
    }

    if (board[0][0] + board[1][0] + board[2][0] == 15) {
        btnA3.setText("Ax");
        win = 1;
    }

    if (board[0][0] + board[1][0] + board[2][0] == 30) {
        btnA3.setText("Ao");
        win = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: try `public`, not `Public`.

Comment: Java is case sensitive and all keywords are in lower case.  Before you write a lot of code in your IDE I suggest you run and test very simple portions of code before adding more code. I also suggest you learn how to use loops (as this code can be replaced with a couple of loops)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java the right `keyword` is `public` not `Public`, indeed it is case sensitive.

You can find the list of all the existing keywords in Java and their meaning [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords).